# module 'pygame.display' has no attribute 'fill'?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to add a start screen to my pgame.
here is the code:

```
def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pygame.display.fill(BLACK)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('Arial',10)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("this is a game", largeText)
        textRect.centre = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
        pygame.display.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
    pygame.display.update()
score = 000 
# Game loop
game_intro()
```

and here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harrisonj11/NetBeansProjects/game_test_jakob/src/game_test_jakob.py", line 167, in <module>
    game_intro()
  File 

"/Users/harrisonj11/NetBeansProjects/game_test_jakob/src/game_test_jakob.py", line 157, in game_intro
    pygame.display.fill(BLACK)

AttributeError: module 'pygame.display' has no attribute 'fill'
```

Here is all the code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/63u9yrfzagerwhz/game_test_jakob.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do screen operations directly on the "pygame.ds=isplay" module - when they should be done on a special Surface object that is initialized as the display by `pygame.display.set_mode`

Insert the line

```
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
```

in the beginning of your function, and change the calls you make to `pygame.display.fill` and `pygame.display.blit` to just `display.fill` and `display.blit`  - but keep the `pygame.display.update()` as is.